# Power Query Remove Values with specific values in the string

Tags: excel, transform, powerquery

I am trying to remove the value of the person's surname if the string contains and of the following values `"Ltd","Limited","LLP","T/A","Plc"`.

The code I have built so turns all of the surnames into errors and I am struggling to understand why. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
#"Move Company Names to New Column", 
{{"Person Surname",
each if Text.Length(_) > 20 or 
List.MatchesAny({"Ltd","Limited","LLP","T/A","Plc"}, (s)=> Text.Contains([Person Surname], s, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) then null 
else _}})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
#"Move Company Names to New Column", 
{{"Person Surname",
each if Text.Length(_) > 20 or 
List.MatchesAny({"Ltd","Limited","LLP","T/A","Plc"}, (s)=> Text.Contains(_, s, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) then null 
else _}})
```

Comment: Thank you very much this now works. For future reference could you tell me where the fault was please?

Comment: [Person Surname] needed to be _ in Text.Contains

Comment: As @horseyride implies, it has to do with, in the context, what is returned by the whole column reference `[Person Surname]` vs the  `_` token

Comment: Thank you, I did just put them side by side to break them down and see where the difference was. Thank you for the assistance